# Creating Google Docs file by getting data from Google Sheets.

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I am an experienced programmer who isn't experienced with using the script editor of Google Drive. 
Since I need to make some reports, I was wondering about ways to exploit the script functionale of Google Drive to ease my process.

So my goal is there's this format that I created in Words, and for some parts of the Words, I need to put in each student's score. However, as doing this manually is very demanding, i was wondering ways to utilize google sheets and google docs for this.

So I was wondering if there's a way for me to get certain data from the spreadsheet (one column for each doc) and put the numbers in the appropriate space in the google docs file, and save it in google drive or send it as an email. Then, I will repeat this process for each column in the spreadsheet until everyone's report has been created.

If you professional programmers can help me out here it will be deeply appreciated. I never had any experience with google script editor and I do not know where to start. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take the [tour]. Questions asking for tutorials, providing or even only recommending, are off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: You're an experienced programmer and you don't know where to start? Did you look at the [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/)

Answer (score 1):

You may check this [Script for generating Google documents from Google spreadsheet data source](https://opensourcehacker.com/2013/01/21/script-for-generating-google-documents-from-google-spreadsheet-data-source/) tutorial.

```
/**
 * Generate Google Docs based on a template document and data incoming from a Google Spreadsheet
 *
 * License: MIT
 *
 * Copyright 2013 Mikko Ohtamaa, http://opensourcehacker.com
 */

// Row number from where to fill in the data (starts as 1 = first row)
var CUSTOMER_ID = 1;

// Google Doc id from the document template
// (Get ids from the URL)
var SOURCE_TEMPLATE = "xxx";

// In which spreadsheet we have all the customer data
var CUSTOMER_SPREADSHEET = "yyy";

// In which Google Drive we toss the target documents
var TARGET_FOLDER = "zzz";

/**
 * Return spreadsheet row content as JS array.
 *
 * Note: We assume the row ends when we encounter
 * the first empty cell. This might not be 
 * sometimes the desired behavior.
 *
 * Rows start at 1, not zero based!!! 
 *
 */
function getRowAsArray(sheet, row) {
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 99);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var columns = [];

  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];

    Logger.log("Got row", row);

    for(var l=0; l<99; l++) {
        var col = row[l];
        // First empty column interrupts
        if(!col) {
            break;
        }

        columns.push(col);
    }
  }

  return columns;
}

/**
 * Duplicates a Google Apps doc
 *
 * @return a new document with a given name from the orignal
 */
function createDuplicateDocument(sourceId, name) {
    var source = DocsList.getFileById(sourceId);
    var newFile = source.makeCopy(name);

    var targetFolder = DocsList.getFolderById(TARGET_FOLDER);
    newFile.addToFolder(targetFolder);

    return DocumentApp.openById(newFile.getId());
}

/**
 * Search a paragraph in the document and replaces it with the generated text 
 */
function replaceParagraph(doc, keyword, newText) {
  var ps = doc.getParagraphs();
  for(var i=0; i<ps.length; i++) {
    var p = ps[i];
    var text = p.getText();

    if(text.indexOf(keyword) >= 0) {
      p.setText(newText);
      p.setBold(false);
    }
  } 
}

/**
 * Script entry point
 */
function generateCustomerContract() {

  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById(CUSTOMER_SPREADSHEET);

  // XXX: Cannot be accessed when run in the script editor?
  // WHYYYYYYYYY? Asking one number, too complex?
  //var CUSTOMER_ID = Browser.inputBox("Enter customer number in the spreadsheet", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if(!CUSTOMER_ID) {
      return; 
  }

  // Fetch variable names
  // they are column names in the spreadsheet
  var sheet = data.getSheets()[0];
  var columns = getRowAsArray(sheet, 1);

  Logger.log("Processing columns:" + columns);

  var customerData = getRowAsArray(sheet, CUSTOMER_ID);  
  Logger.log("Processing data:" + customerData);

  // Assume first column holds the name of the customer
  var customerName = customerData[0];

  var target = createDuplicateDocument(SOURCE_TEMPLATE, customerName + " agreement");

  Logger.log("Created new document:" + target.getId());

  for(var i=0; i<columns.length; i++) {
      var key = columns[i] + ":"; 
      // We don't replace the whole text, but leave the template text as a label
      var text = customerData[i] || ""; // No Javascript undefined
      var value = key + " " + text;
      replaceParagraph(target, key, value);
  }

}
```

As @James Donnellan stated, please check the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) on how to use the service which allows scripts to create, access, and modify Google Sheets files.